# Is there an alternate keyboard combination for the Up key in bash?

Tags: bash

I recently discovered that, in a terminal, Ctrl-i is the same as Tab (which is very useful on my phone, where there are no arrow keys nor tab).

On a normal terminal pressing the up key navigates the history.

Is there another way to recall the last command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> to move backwards in the command history

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd> to move forward in the command history

(Somewhere I read that it is with the Alt key, but Ctrl is what works for me)

Comment: And Ctrl-A to move the cursor at the beginning and Ctrl-E moves the cursor to the end :)

Comment: This also works with `fzf` plugin when you press **Ctrl+r** to show the command history. You can browse command history using **Ctrl+p** and **Ctrl+n**.

Answer (score 2):

You could, if it helps type `!-1` which would be the last command you typed.

If you wanted the second last you typed then `!-2` and as the **man history** says:

**Event Designators**

```
An event designator is a reference to a command line entry in the  history  list.  
Unless  the reference is absolute, events are relative to the current position in   
the history list.

   !      Start a history substitution, except when followed by  a  blank,
          newline, = or (.
   !n     Refer to command line n.
   !-n    Refer to the current command minus n.
   !!     Refer to the previous command.  This is a synonym for `!-1'.
   !string
          Refer  to the most recent command preceding the current position
          in the history list starting with string.
   !?string[?]
          Refer to the most recent command preceding the current postition
          in  the  history  list containing string.  The trailing ? may be
          omitted if string is followed immediately by a newline.
   ^string1^string2^
          Quick substitution.  Repeat the last command, replacing  string1
          with string2.  Equivalent to ``!!:s/string1/string2/'' (see Mod‐
          ifiers below).
   !#     The entire command line typed so far.
```

You can also use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to go back one history command at a time.
Use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to go forward one history command at a time.